# Logging in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Basically, the script will remotely create a folder "TestFolder" in the desktop that was provided by the user. I want a logging function that will append the output from `Write-Host` for each desktop.

```
$filepath = ".\input.txt"
$logpath  = ".\log_computername.log"

while ($server = (Read-Host "Server")) {
    $server.Trim() | Out-File $filepath -Append
}

$test1 = {
    $createfolder = "C:\TestFolder"
    Write-Log "Creating folder in $env:COMPUTERNAME"

    New-Item -Path $createfolder -ItemType Directory -Force
    Write-Log "Done"
}

foreach ($comp1 in $comp_array) {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $comp1 -ScriptBlock $test1
}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to achieve. Do you just want a function `Write-Log` that would log the given strings to a file in the directory you created? How would it be able to write there *before* you create the directory? What do you mean by "desktop that was provided by the user"?

Comment: sorry, so the script will ask user to provide the target server/desktop. I need function that will save the output of Write-Host. Let's say i provided  3 desktops pc1/pc2/pc3

Server:pc1
Server:pc2
Server:pc3

I want to have a logfile for each, and the sample log content is:
"Creating folder in #env:computername
Done"

I also want to include the error messages in the logfile

Comment: Do you actually want `Write-Host` output redirected to a file? Because that's not what the cmdlet was made for. Is anything wrong with `'log message' | Add-Content 'your.log'`? And do you want the files created locally or on the remote host?

Comment: Or can just use Start/Stop-Transcript inside a function?

Comment: I find the log that I'm looking for in Start/Stop-Transcript but it only create 1 log file for all the PCs. I tried to include it in the $test1 so it will create log file every instance but my session is not doing anything upon executing it.

Comment: Please answer the questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do it. I added " $compname(gets the computer name the remote session) before the Start-Transcript. Logging is now working as expected. Thanks for your help guys.

```
$filepath = ".\input.txt"
$logpath  = ".\log_$compname.log"

while ($server = (Read-Host "Server")) {
    $server.Trim() | Out-File $filepath -Append
}

$test1 = {
    $createfolder = "C:\TestFolder"
    Write-Log "Creating folder in $env:COMPUTERNAME"

    New-Item -Path $createfolder -ItemType Directory -Force
    Write-Log "Done"
}

foreach ($comp1 in $comp_array) {

   $compname ="Invoke-Command -ComputerName $comp1 -ScriptBlock {$env:computername}"

   $logpath  = ".\$compname.log"
   Start-Transcript -Path $logpath

    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $comp1 -ScriptBlock $test1

    Stop-Transcript
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage `System.IO.File` and its `AppendAllText` which creates a new file if it does not exist and appends text to that file. Note that it is not going to create a folder structure for you. A very simple way of how to output some text would be

```
Function Write-LogFile([string] $logText) {
    [System.IO.File]::AppendAllText("Your log file path.txt", $logText + [Environment]::NewLine, [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8);
}

Write-LogFile("Starting up " + [System.DateTime]::Now);
Write-LogFile("Copying files");
```

Comment: Hi,
I found out how to do it: